# SQL Performance when using different tables or different databases

Tags: sql-server, database-performance, query-performance

Currently, I have a SQL database with a lot of customers.

I have a table store data of all customers. Now I want to split data, each table will store data of each customer. Or each database will store data of each customer.

I'm confused about performance of SQL. Which way is best solution? Store on each table at the same database or store on each database?

Comment: *"Now I want to split data, each table will store data of each customer. Or each database will store data of each customer."* That sounds like a horrifically bad idea. Keep all your customers in one place. A single table for each customer (or even worse, database) is never going to be maintainable or scalable. Can you imagine if Amazon has a different table or database for **every** one of their customers? They would 100's of millions of tables or databases...

Comment: Relational databases are very good at managing this problem, you just identify which customer the rows belong to, index them, and keep them all in the same table.

Comment: In regards to your question *"Which way is best solution?"* this is far too broad or going to generate opinionated answers, and you have my opinion: Don't do either, both are a **bad** idea.

Comment: @Larnu very true what you said but what if a few customers wants to have a separation (schema/tables) from other customers because of there company regulations i have encounterd this in the past a few times where i worked..

Comment: That description sounds more like your hosting a customer's data, @RaymondNijland ; which is a very different scenario. The OP describes they have a table of customers and they want to use a different database/table to store the data of said customer. They haven't said they are hosting the data for their customers, and all the different details are in different tables. For your scenario, certainly different databases may be needed, but the OP appears to be talking about the details of a single individual here.

Comment: *"That description sounds more like your hosting a customer's data, ... which is a very different scenario. "* indeed it was a combination of a custom build CMS and CRM with also custom build modules for companies to store there data or to automate there process ... *"For your scenario, certainly different databases may be needed, but the OP appears to be talking about the details of a single individual here."* Yes might be not sure @Larnu because i was not sure i also posted that comment..

Answer (score 1):

As explained in comments both ways (that you describe) is not a good idea. If you want to increase performance of database then correct use indexes. Also you may look at  partitioned table:

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/12/table-partitioning-in-sql-server/